# Интеграция с amocrm, добавление лида в Неразобранное

Tags: php, amocrm

Всем привет.
Делаю интеграцию с amocrm, все ок, но заказчик попросил, что бы лиды добавлялись в папку Неразобранное. Раньше в данных передавалось только название сделки, по умолчанию она шла в папку Новая заявка. Сейчас в данных передаю поле status_id с соответствующим id и получаю ошибку
"code":"NotSupportedChoice",
"path":"status_id",
"detail":"The value you selected is not a valid choice."

Если в качестве id передать другой (например id той же папки, в которую шло изначально по умолчанию, то все ок. id других папок - тоже добавляется как нужно), но если передать именно id Неразобранное, то такая ошибка.
Может кто сталкивался с подобной ошибкой, уже несколько часов сижу, не понимаю, что еще попробовать[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: Поискала еще информацию, нашла, что через api доступно только два типа неразобранного: формы и звонки, лиды нельзя.